# Vee-validate regex rule is showing error even with match

Tags: regex, vue.js, vee-validate, vue-validator

Attempting to write a regex to match a UUID - using a validator online was able to successfully prove regex is supposed to work, however, vee-validate still marks it as an error... any ideas?

```
<form @submit.prevent="performSearch">
    <div class="msg-box">
        <validation-provider v-slot="{ errors }" rules="regex: /^[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12}$/i">
            <input v-model="appliance...." name="id" class="search-param" placeholder="Full ..." />
            <span class="has-text-danger has-text-weight-bold is-size-8 msg">{{ errors[0] ? 'Pleas...' : '' }}</span>
        </validation-provider>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="button is-info">
        Filter
    </button>
    <button @click.prevent="clearSearch()" class="button is-light">Reset</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you add the error in your question?

Answer (score 0):

`rules` prop should not be string. Try this:

```
<ValidationProvider
      :rules="{
        regex: /^[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12}$/i,
      }"
      class="MyClass"
      tag="div"
      style="width: 50%"
>
```